# Repair broken xattr on macOS?

Tags: macos, xattr

I don't know what happened, but it seems my xattr is broken.

```
% which xattr
/usr/bin/xattr


% xattr -h
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/xattr-2.7", line 7, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
ImportError: No module named pkg_resources
```

I found out, that module pkg_resources is part of setuptools. So I installed setuptools via pip3, but it is already there.

```
%  pip3 install setuptools
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (41.2.0)
```

xattr-2.7 is just a simple code

```
#!/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
import sys
sys.argv[0] = sys.argv[0].replace('-2.7', '')
# EASY-INSTALL-ENTRY-SCRIPT: 'xattr==0.6.4','console_scripts','xattr'
__requires__ = 'xattr==0.6.4'
import sys
from pkg_resources import load_entry_point

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(
        load_entry_point('xattr==0.6.4', 'console_scripts', 'xattr')()
    )
```

/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python does exist and can not be altered in anyway.
How can I fix this? I'm on macOS Mojave.

Comment: Try `type xattr` rather than `which xattr` It should say `xattr is hashed (/usr/bin/xattr)`

Comment: `% type xattr
xattr is /usr/bin/xattr`

Comment: Ok, try `/usr/bin/xattr -h`

Comment: Its the same like above. `% /usr/bin/xattr -h
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/xattr-2.7", line 7, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
ImportError: No module named pkg_resources`

Comment: Ok, last question. What do you get with `file /usr/bin/xattr`

Comment: `file /usr/bin/xattr
/usr/bin/xattr: Python script text executable, ASCII text`

Comment: Ok, so you have somehow overwritten the Apple-supplied `/usr/bin/xattr` command that comes with macOS, with a Python script. You'll need to either restore the Apple-supplied `xattr` from a backup, or copy one from another Mac.

Comment: Overwritten the Apple-supplied `/usr/bin/xattr` ? How can this happen? It might be a bit tricky to restore `/usr/bin/xattr`, because `/usr/bin` is a restricted directory. There is no legal way to write or delete in that directory. So I wonder how it happened, that I have overwritten a file in that directory. Would it help to reinstall macOS Mojave?

Comment: To answer my own question, yes, it does help to reinstall macOS Mojave. Thanks for the hint and your assistance.